# Shell CollectionView is not updating Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make CollectionView in Shell but it's not updating.
I have one view model connected to Page and AppShell but when I update Collection view only page is updationg.

```
`public class AppShellViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Command Load { get; }

    public ObservableCollection<ListData> _lists { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ListData> Lists 
    {   
        get { return _lists; }
        set
        { 
            _lists = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }




    public AppShellViewModel()
    {

        Lists = new ObservableCollection<ListData>()
        {
            new ListData(){id=0,name="test",UserId=0},
            new ListData(){id=1,name="test1",UserId=1},
            new ListData(){id=2,name="test2",UserId=2},
            new ListData(){id=3,name="test3",UserId=3},
            new ListData(){id=4,name="test4",UserId=4}
        };
        Load = new Command(async () => await GetUserLists());
    }



    async Task GetUserLists()
    {
        for (int i = 5; i < 15; i++)
        {
            Lists.Add(new ListData {id=i, name=$"test{ i }", UserId=i });
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}`
```

Then i have App Shell Collection View

```
`<Shell.FlyoutContent>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#34495e">
        <Label Text="YOUR LISTS" FontSize="50" />
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Lists}" >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:ListData">
                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" 
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            FontSize="13" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</Shell.FlyoutContent>`
```

And There is Page CollectionView

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ToDoApp.Views.AboutPage"
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:ToDoApp.Models">
<StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Load" Command="{Binding Load}"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding error}"/>

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Lists}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:ListData">
                    <Label Text="{Binding name}" 
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            FontSize="13" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>`
```

before update it looks like this
[Page before update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZgYJ.png)
[Shell before update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2l3a.png)

And after update the only what changed is content page and shell is the same as before
[Page after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz1W2.png)
[Shell after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nze2.png)

Comment: are both lists using the same **instance** of the VM?  You do not show where the VM is created or assigned so I can't tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to Jason's comment.

**WON'T CHANGE TOGETHER**

NOT the same instance - BindingContexts similar to these:

```cs
// In AppShell.xaml.cs.
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new AppShellViewModel();
}

// In AboutPage.xaml.cs.
public AboutPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new AppShellViewModel();
}
```

---

**GOOD (SHARED BETWEEN TWO PLACES)**

BindingContexts are SAME instance:

```cs
// In AppShellViewModel.cs.
public class AppShellViewModel ...
{
    private static AppShellViewModel _it;
    public static AppShellViewModel It
    {
        get {
            if (_it == null)
                _it = new AppShellViewModel();
            return _it;
        }
    }
}

// In AppShell.xaml.cs.
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = AppShellViewModel.It;
}

// In AboutPage.xaml.cs.
public AboutPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = AppShellViewModel.It;
}
```